# How can I avoid including a scaling component in a morph target?

Tags: mesh, export, scale

I made a prop in Blender and created some morph targets for exporting to Poser. The final mesh comprised 9 cylinders and 2 toroids. The build involved the following steps:

1) Setting the units to Metric.

2) Joining the primitives.

3) Moving the origin point.

4) Applying a mirror modifier.

5) Converting to a single vertex group.

I then exported the base mesh and morph targets to Poser. Poser created a morph dial and the morph action worked as expected. However, the morph dial also scaled the prop. How can I check that the mesh is "raw mesh" without embeded scaling data that could be causing the problem?